# Javascript async load with jquery append() function inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

**Edit:** I am looking for a way to async "include" a javascript file inside another.

What if I load a javascript file like this:

```
<script src="http://my.website.com/file.js" async="" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Inside the javascript file I have

```
$('head').append('<script src="http://other-website.com/other-file.js" type="text/javascript"></script>');
```

Will this file still be loaded async including the `other-file.js`?

I am guessing that I need to append it with async like that

```
$('head').append('<script async="" src="http://other-website.com/other-file.js" type="text/javascript"></script>');
```

To completely load all javascript async, right?

But inside `other-file.js` there are functions which I am using inside `file.js`

Comment: Developer tools in your browser (Chrome / FF / IE) can verify this for you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you would need to add the `async` attribute, and if you depend on that other file, you'll need some complex logic to know when it gets loaded.

There are libraries built for this exact purpose, have you looked into them? I could recommend [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/), this way you can wrap your code like this:

```
require(["helper/util"], function(util) {
    //This function is called when scripts/helper/util.js is loaded.
    //If util.js calls define(), then this function is not fired until
    //util's dependencies have loaded, and the util argument will hold
    //the module value for "helper/util".
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where the JS is running that has the `.append()` line in it, and whether *it* has the `async` attribute.

If it is running in the `head` of your document, and it is appending to `head`, then it will not be asynchronous (will block) if the appended `<script>` tag doesn't have the `async` attribute.

The reason is that `file.js` will very likely load and be parsed before the `<head>` of the document is done being processed. JavaScript will block the browser's HTTP connection until it's done parsing any external JS without `async`, which means and it will add the new `<script>` tag below it in the `<head>` and then proceed to process it and block the HTTP connection, unless the `async` attribute is present.